# Systematically testing django application with PayPal and other such externally dependant services

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a django application which accepts PayPal payments using

I am testing different scenarios manually PayPal's Sandbox API. I want to make it more systematic specifically from two angles:

1) While writing code and testing things out, I don't want to go through a lot of clicks to stimulate a PayPal IPN. Whats the best way to generate quickly generate IPN for a particular scenario.
2) On a more general level, how do I Unit Test any application which interfaces with external services like IMAP, PayPal IPN, web services etc.?

Answer (score 0):

1. Organise your code so that you can just invoke the routine that calls the paypal ipn itself with the desired arguments from a unittest.
2. learn unittesting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/